# Beautiful soup remove superscripts

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

How do I remove the superscripts from all of the text? I have code below that gets all visible text, but the superscripts for footnoting are messing things up. How do I remove them?

for example `Active accounts (1),(2)`, `(1),(2)` are visible superscripts.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from bs4.element import Comment
import requests


f_url='https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1633917/000163391718000094/exhibit991prq12018pypl.htm'

def tag_visible(element):
    if element.parent.name in ['style', 'script', 'head', 'title', 'meta', '[document]']:
        return False
    if isinstance(element, Comment):
        return False
    return True


def text_from_html(body):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(body, 'html.parser')
    texts = soup.findAll(text=True)
    visible_texts = filter(tag_visible, texts)  
    return u" ".join(t.strip() for t in visible_texts)

html = requests.get(f_url)
text= text_from_html(html.text)
```

Comment: wow... didn't know `sup` was an option. put it in the answer below and I will give you credit for it.

Comment: Glad I could help – and good thing the most basic solution worked! (Per the possible reasons it could *not* have worked.) If you run into one of those reasons need help with fine-tuning the `tag_visible` function, just say so. It would probably need an example of your HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The BeautifulSoup function [`find_all`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all) returns a list of all single discrete HTML elements in the input (`find_all` is the proper function to use in BeautifulSoup 4 and preferred over `findAll`). The next function, [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter), goes through this list and removes the items for which its callback routine returns `False`. The callback function tests the tag name of each snippet and returns `False` if it's in the not-wanted list, `True` otherwise.

If these superscripts are always indicated by the proper HTML tag `sup` then you can add it to the not-wanted list in the callback function.

Possible pitfalls are:

1. It is assumed that the literal (semantically correct) tag `sup` is used, and not, for example, a class or a span that merely *specifies* `vertical-align: superscript;` in its CSS;
2. It is assumed that you want to get rid of *all* elements that are in this superscript tag. If there are exceptions ("the 20<sup>th</sup> century"), you can check the text contents; for example, only remove if its contents are all numerical. If there are exceptions to *that* ("a<sup>2</sup> = b<sup>2</sup> + c<sup>2</sup>"), you will have to check for a wider context, or build a whitelist or blacklist of inclusions/exclusions.