# Beautifulsoup superscript not "sup"

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I can eliminate the superscript from the following page:

https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1633917/000163391718000094/exhibit991prq12018pypl.htm

with this post here: [Beautiful soup remove superscripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51115590/beautiful-soup-remove-superscripts)

but now I have a superscript that is not tagged `sup`

https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1549802/000110465918031489/a18-13128_1ex99d1.htm

Behind `Net revenues` is a superscript `1` that has no `sup` tag.

How do I remove this superscript from the text like the post here: [Beautiful soup remove superscripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51115590/beautiful-soup-remove-superscripts) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the element in question has the following format:

```
<font size="1" style="font-size:6.5pt;font-weight:bold;position:relative;top:-3.0pt;">1</font>
```

So we can see here that they are formatting text with a font that the important parts of this are the style `position:relative` and `top:` values. I would personally write a function that could be extended that detects superscripts and removes them. For example:

```
def Remove_Superscripts(soup):
    # Simple superscript extraction
    for element in soup.find_all('sup'):
        element.extract()

    # More complex superscript extraction for this example:
    for element in soup.find_all(lambda e: e and e.name == 'font' and e.has_attr('style') and
                                           'position:relative' in e['style'] and
                                           'top:' in e['style']:
        element.extract()
```

This is a very lazy and messy example, but it should give you an idea on how you can remove the superscript tags that aren't marked with a `<sup\>` tag. Unfortunately you will need to extend and modify this method (I'd work on making it as open and generic as possible) each time you encounter a new case where someone has constructed a superscript differently.

Answer (score 0):

something like this:

```
fonts = soup.select('font[style*="position:relative"]')
for font in fonts:
    font.decompose()
```